# I need to read individual rows in a CSV, make calculations from values in those rows (x2), and then append those rows with the new values

Tags: python-2.7

I have a .CSV that I'm attempting to read individual rows from, make calculations from individual values in the rows, then append the values resulting from the calculations to the end  of that row.  My approach is to iterate through each row, call the value, make the calc from that value, then append to that row.  Here's mu current code (at one point I managed to append all the calcs to the last row of the csv row, which was promising but incorrect, right now I'm getting a "'_csv.writer' object is not iterable" type error):

```
import csv 
import math

f = open('planet_data.csv','a+')
writer = csv.writer(f)

for row in writer:                  <- loction of error
    if row[1] == 'Planet_Radius':   <- To bypass csv header values
        pass
    else:
        a = int(row[1])
        b = str((4/3)*math.pi*(a**3))
        row.writerow(b)
        print row
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm guessing the code will still need to work after the iterator issue is resolved.  Also, I'm guessing there are packages/modules that can simplify this, but the point of this exercise is to learn how to manually loop through csvs.

Comment: It would be easier and safer to write to a second csv file.  Eventually you will encounter an unescaped quote or something you didn't anticipate and your program will crash leaving you with mangled, partially updated data file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will be able to write changes in the same file,
but you can create a new one this way:

```
with open("planet_data.csv", "rb") as infile, open('planet_data_2.csv', "wb") as outfile:
   reader = csv.reader(infile)
   next(reader, None)  # skip the header
   writer = csv.writer(outfile)
   for row in reader:
       a = int(row[1])
       b = str((4/3)*math.pi*(a**3))
       writer.writerow(b)
```

I hope this will help!